# Angular application Msal requires login in a new tab

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

So currently when I use my application it's working great in navigating to new views etc, but when I copy paste a link into a new tab I get to the login view where it says this user is logged in but I still have to click on it to get to the view. I figure it's because msal is storing everything in sessionStorage, and that storage doesnt persist when I open a new tab.

How can I get around this? I figure localStorage might be a good way, but I cant seem to figure out how to configure that.

I have these settings:

```
 azure: {
clientID: 'xxxxxx',
authority: 'xxxxxxx',
redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
cache: {
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
}
```

And the routes look like this:

```
path: 'home',
loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
canActivate: [MsalGuard]
```

As you see I try and set cacheLocation to localstorage like this but its still set in sessionStorage, and from other threads I gather that this is by design. So maybe I dont want to store this in localstorage? But then how would I set this up so I dont have to login when opening a new tab.

Any links to some helpful docs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Angular is this? How does the configuration go to MSAL? It seems to me that the cache setting is not set correctly.

Comment: @juunas 

Its Angular: 8.2.14

In app.module.ts its configured like this: @NgModule({ .... Imports:
[ MsalModule.forRoot(azure) ] <-- the values you saw in OP. I assume thats what you mean by configuration.

Comment: You can find an example how to configure MSAL here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/configuration.md#msalmoduleforroot. It looks quite different from yours, could you try it?

Comment: Thank you, yes I am currently trying to, but I get this: "Argument of type 'PublicClientApplication' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MsalConfig'.
  Property 'clientID' is missing in type 'PublicClientApplication' but required in type 'MsalConfig'" even though it's defined in the object. Not sure why that is but I will get back to you once Ive solved it. Appreciate your help :)!

Comment: Ah, there is probably a version difference :\

Comment: Yes it seems like that, trying to find the right version documentation right now. 

Do you think setting the cache to localStorage is best when it comes to keeping the user logged in when the user opens the app in a new page?

Comment: solved it, the object I put into forRoot was built wrong. I had cache: {cacheLocation: 'localStorage'} but it was supposed to only be cacheLocation: 'localStorage' and it worked. Unreal!

Thank you for the help juunas, I appreciate your efforts in guiding me. If I remember correctly you were also the one who helped me way back when I was stuck in azure functions. I appreciate you very much, cheers!

Comment: Good to hear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it, the object I put into forRoot was built wrong. I had

```
cache: {cacheLocation: 'localStorage'}
```

but it was supposed to only be `cacheLocation: 'localStorage'` and it worked.